# Axios is returning a string called "Array" instead of an object

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, vue-component, axios

The following code in my Vue app returns data as a string called "Array" when it should be returning an object. Code is simplified for the sake of brevity:

**Component.vue**

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post(URL_HERE)
    .then(function(response) {
        // success
        console.log(response);
})
```

this returns the following, which is wrong as I'm expecting an object with a token.

```
{data: "Array", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {content-type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"}, config: Object, …}
```

---

However if I use **XMLHttpRequest()** in the same way it returns what I'm after successfully. Why would Axios be returning a string called "Array"?

This is what comes back from XMLHttpRequest:

```
{__ob__:Observer, token: "123456" }
```

Comment: try console.log(response.data);

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this problem after much searching. Adding the following headers made everything work as expected:

```
axios.post(URL, '', {
        headers: {
           'Accept': '*/*'
        }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add empty "data" object for your `post`, something like 
`axios.post(URL_HERE,{})`

Comment: I'm still getting the same result, it's so odd. Could it be header related or something?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Please, can you check your request-headers Content-Type?

Comment: I'm getting 'Content-Type": [ "text/plain;charset=UTF-8' through Axios. Also tried vue-resource and got the same result :/